# RED.httpAdmin.get sending old data nodered

Tags: node-red

I'm trying to transfer data between html and js file in my custom node. In my js file I'm crawling all opcua items and send it to html file to show them on table. This works on first time but when I deploy again RED.httpAdmin.get endpoint just keep sending the old data.

HTML Part (in oneditprepare function), since I do not know when crawl method end, I'm sending request in every seconds and check if data length is bigger than zero.:

```js
      const fetch = setInterval(() => {
        $.getJSON("plc-options" + this.id, function (data) {
          if (data.length > 0) {
            $("#node-input-plc-options").append(`${data}`);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              generateOption(data[i]);
            }
            $("#loading").empty().remove();
            clearInterval(fetch);
          }
        });
      }, 1000);
```

JS Part:

```js
     let items = [];
     RED.httpAdmin.get("/plc-options" + node.id, function (req, res) {
            res.json(items);
        });

        async function setupClient(url) {
            const client = opcua.OPCUAClient.create(connectionOption);
            try {
                await client.connect(url);
                const session = await client.createSession(userIdentity);
                var crawler = new NodeCrawler(session);
                node.status({
                    fill: "blue",
                    shape: "dot",
                    text: "Browsing variables in the server.",
                });
                const tempItems = [];
                crawler.on("browsed", function (element) {
                    // 2 means variable type
                    if (element.nodeClass === 2 && element.accessLevel === 3) {
                        tempItems.push(element);
                    }
                });
                await crawler.read(node.topic);
                items = [...tempItems];
                node.status({
                    fill: "green",
                    shape: "dot",
                    text: "Successfully found all variables.",
                });
                client.disconnect();
            }
            catch (err) {
                node.status({
                    fill: "red",
                    shape: "dot",
                    text: err,
                });
            }
        }
        node.on("input", function (msg) {
            if (this.plcName === '') {
                node.status({
                    fill: "red",
                    shape: "dot",
                    text: "Please fill plc name area.",
                });
            }
            setupClient(opcuaEndpoint.endpoint);
        });
        node.on("close", function () {
            items = [];
        });
```

After clicking to deploy, response sending empty array and stay like that even items element changed. It's probably because setting `items = [];` in `node.close` but if I do not this, this time again it is showing the previous items value. (browser is not caching anything postman res is also showing the old items).  How can I send latest items value?

Comment: We would really need to see all the code in the `.js` file to answer this properly. The code as it is doesn't make any sense as it is as it's missing where the node setup code.

Comment: Hi, setting and getting items to node.context solved my issue. Previously I defined items array just bellow `RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);` and I was making it empty in `node.close` so in deploy items becoming empty again. But problem was `RED.httpAdmin.get` endpoint just keep sending empty array, even though setupClient run and change the items again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting and getting items to node.context solved my issue. Previously I defined items array just bellow RED.nodes.createNode(this, config); and I was making it empty in node.close so in deploy items becoming empty again. But problem was RED.httpAdmin.get endpoint just keep sending empty array, even though setupClient ran and changed the items again.

For more info about context you can check out [node-red-context](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/context).

Comment: Context is probably the wrong solution here, what is needed is probably too just move it to a slightly higher scope and to not clear it in on `on('close')`